# no loaded event for handlebar templates

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, handlebars.js, client-side-templating

I'm using handlebars and handlebar jquery plugin with bootstrap modal .. my problem is that handlebar library does not provide any proper events that will be fired after a given template is compiled and rendered thus making my UI not interactive or have issues in the way they display.

Currently this code only shows correctly if I put an alert statement on top of it :

```
// the modal appears out of place
$modal.render('BootstrapModalTemplate', context)

// this makes my modal render correctly
alert('Works');
$modal.render('BootstrapModalTemplate', context)
```

Can you help guyz ? is there a way to hookup a callback after the template has been fully loaded and rendered ?